# How to ask gnutls to use client certificate in emacs 24

Tags: emacs, ssl, emacs24

I'm trying to use client certificate to authenticate to an irc server. In emacs 23, I was able to use tls-program variable to do so:

(setq tls-program '("gnutls-cli --priority secure256 --x509cafile /home/me/CAs.pem  --x509certfile /home/me/nick.pem -p %p %h"))

However, the support in emacs24 is native using libgnutls and does not use external program, hence it ignores tls-program variable.

Could someone tell me, what's the alternative way to define a default client certificate in emacs 24?

Answer (score 4):

The only option I've found out is not to use the built-in GnuTLS support by redefining `gnutls-available-p`.
E.g.:

```
(defun gnutls-available-p ()
  "Function redefined in order not to use built-in GnuTLS support"
  nil)
```

Your settings using `tls-program` will then work as they did before switching to Emacs 24.  There is no other way to specify client certificates for now.  The only relevant available setting for the built-in gnutls library seems to be `gnutls-trustfiles`.